# Foreach dentro de otro Foreach

Tags: laravel, foreach, blade

Tengo 2 apis que tengo que anidar para obtener unos datos y de la 2nda el logo de los datos anterioers.

```php
     $url= 'https://dominio1.com';
            $client = new \GuzzleHttp\Client();
            $res = $client->get($url);
            $content = (string) $res->getBody();
     $results = json_decode($content, true);
```

Esto me devuelve los datos y los recojo de la siguiente manera:

```php
    @foreach($results['resultadoApi'] as $result)
    {{ $result['idEmpresa'] . - .$result['NombreEmpresa'] }}
    @endforeach
```

esto me muestra por ejemplo:

```
4567 Empresa1
5976 Empresa2 ... etc etc
```

Ahora bien tengo una segunda API que enviando el idEmpresa me devuelve el logo en base64.

```php
foreach($results['resultadoApi'] as $result)
        {
    $url2= 'https://dominio.com/logo/'.$result['id'].'';
            $client2 = new \GuzzleHttp\Client();
            $res2 = $client2->get($url2);
            $content2 = (string) $res2->getBody();
```

Este ejemplo me devuelve de 4567 el logo...

Ahora bien yo necesitaría que me quedara algo asi:

```php
    @foreach($results['resultadoApi'] as $result)
    {{$logoEmpresa}} - {{ $result['idEmpresa'] . - .$result['NombreEmpresa'] }}
    @endforeach
```

y que quede

```
Logo1 - 4567 Empresa1
Logo2 - 5976 Empresa2... etc
```

probé en la vista : agregando

```
<img src="data:image/png;base64, {{ $content2 }}" alt="Image Preview" />
```

me muestra en todos los resultados la ultima imagen del bucle...

Comment: ¿Y cuál es el problema? ¿Qué has intentado?

Comment: Supongo que eso mejor que lo resuelvas en PHP antes de enviarlo a la vista. Entiendo que puedes hacer un **foreach()** del primer result y meter la segunda API dentro para añadir el logo en el primer array.  Pruébalo y si no lo consigues edita la pregunta agregando lo que has intentado y que error te ha dado para que podamos ayudarte, gracias.

Comment: Hola, agregué los intentos, el problema que tengo es que o en todos los items me muestra la primer imagen, o en todos los items me muestra la ultima imagen... no me muestra nunca la imagen que le corresponde a cada item

Comment: Pues no se comprende bien tu problema, te retorna siempre la ultima imagen del bucle debido a que la variable content2 siempre se esta sobreescribiendo, al llegar al final del ciclo tomará el ultimo registro,. quieres mostrar todas las empresas con su imagen? o solo una imagen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Voy un poco a ciegas, pero prueba con esto:

```
foreach($results['resultadoApi'] as $clave => $result)
        {
    $url2= 'https://dominio.com/logo/'.$result['id'].'';
            $client2 = new \GuzzleHttp\Client();
            $res2 = $client2->get($url2);
            $content2 = (string) $res2->getBody();
            $results['resultadoApi'][$clave]['logoEmpresa'] = $content2;
```

Y luego, modifica la plantilla así:

```
@foreach($results['resultadoApi'] as $result)
    {{ $result['idEmpresa'] . - .$result['NombreEmpresa'] }}
    <img src="data:image/png;base64, {{ $result['logoEmpresa'] }}" alt="Image Preview" />
@endforeach
```

### Explicación detallada

Se trata de agregar a la variable de array `$results['resultadoApi']` ya existente el nuevo valor de **logoEmpresa** para cada uno de sus elementos, por lo tanto lo que hacemos es un **foreach()** separando lo que es la **clave** (o índice) de cada elemento de su actual contenido **$result** mediante esta instrucción:

```
foreach($results['resultadoApi'] as $clave => $result)
```

Luego, ya dentro de este bucle, ya podemos agregar más datos a cada elemento de array, que queda representado por `$results['resultadoApi'][$clave]`, con lo cual tan solo debemos asignarle un nuevo dato, en este caso **logoEmpresa** de este modo:

```
$results['resultadoApi'][$clave]['logoEmpresa'] = $content2;
```

Finalmente, en la plantilla, cuando volvemos a recorrer el array **$results['resultadoApi']**, podremos llamar al nuevo dato al igual que los demas, en este caso será `$result['logoEmpresa']` el que hemos creado, y lo podemos poner donde sea preciso, siendo en este caso concreto así, pues ese dato contiene el código en base64 de la imagen:

```
<img src="data:image/png;base64, {{ $result['logoEmpresa'] }}" alt="Image Preview" />
```

Comment: Ahhh genial!! no solamente funciona, sino que entendí y aprendí como anidarlo dentro de los datos ya existentes, agregué otras 2 apis mas con los detalles y horarios y va genial! Mil gracias <3!

Comment: Perfecto, me alegro :-)  Acabo de agregar una explicación más detallada a la respuesta para que se vea el porque (aunque ya lo has entendido y eso está genial, pues de eso trata este sitio, de aprender entre todos :-))